# Как сделать автоматический выход используя значение из БД

Tags: yii2, сессия

Столкнулся с проблемой

Я пытаюсь сделать auto lougout и использую данный код

```
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => '30', //секунды
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],

        ],
```

Все работае отлично

Здесь я определил authTimout статически. Но я хочу получить значение тайм-аута из базы данных и установить его в authTimeout.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямо в конфигурации можно задать по умолачнию, так как у вас в примере

```
'authTimeout' => '30', //секунды
```

Если вы хотите брать это значение из базы, единственный способ делать это после создания приложения, например в методе login

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {

            // Устанавливаем значение authTimeout с базы данных
            Yii::$app->user->authTimeout = 'Запрос в базу на получения authTimeout';

            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        }

        return false;
    }
```